# Matlab - Converting an image and saving it to disk

Tags: image, matlab, save

I have converted an image to gray level using the following command: `rgb2gray`.

For example:

```
I = imread('xyz.jpg');
I2 = rgb2gray(I);
```

How can I save the new (converted image) to disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
imwrite(I2,filename,fmt)
```

Reference: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Note: 
The command must be executed like this:

```
imwrite(I2,'xyz.jpg','jpg');
```

The xyz.jpg is the name of your file in the format you need.

The jpg is the format of the image.

Remember, that the image gets saved in your current MATLAB directory...

Answer (score -2):

A way could be:

imshow(`enter code here`I2);

Then, for the figure that shows up, choose `File --> Save` or `File --> Save As...`

Comment: that will save the figure and not the image